# RegisterOnChange is not a function

Tags: angular

I designed this form using FormBuilder(fb)

```
this.serviceRecordForm = this.fb.group({
        client: [],
        serviceRecordItem: this.fb.group({
            productStatus: [''],
            password: [''],
            hasBackup: [''],
            deliveryType: [''],
            product: [''],
            brand: [''],
            serialNumber: [''],
            defect: [''],
        }),
        accesoryList: this.fb.array([''])
    });
```

accesoryList is an array coming from backend. And my HTML form is :

```
            <form [formGroup]="serviceRecordForm" (ngSubmit)="save()">

            <div class="mb-3" *ngFor="let accesory of accesoryList">
                <label for="{{accesory.id}}" class="form-label">{{accesory.name}}
                    <input type="checkbox" id="{{accesory.id}}" formControlName="accesoryList"
                           [ngModel]="accesory"></label>
            </div>

        </form>
```

I am populating this accesoryList inside ngOnInit() method from Restful API.

```
this.accesoryService.getAccesories().subscribe(accesories => {
        this.accesoryList = accesories;
    })
```

Whenever i open my form i can see it properly designed and populated accesoryList from backend but i got this error as much as number of accesoryList.length inside console.

```
ERROR TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function
at setUpModelChangePipeline (forms.mjs:3117:13)
at setUpControl (forms.mjs:2947:5)
at FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.mjs:4771:9)
at FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.mjs:5321:43)
at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.mjs:5266:18)
at FormControlName.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (core.mjs:1521:14)
at callHook (core.mjs:2444:18)
at callHooks (core.mjs:2403:17)
at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:2354:9)
at refreshView (core.mjs:10341:21)
```

i use angular v15 and spring boot backend with spring data jpa

Comment: May I ask why you have a for loop based on the `accesoryList` array, but try to bind to this formArray in each iteration? Is this intential? If yes, can you explain what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: I want to populate my checkbox options with my accesories coming from database. I thought this approach might be useful. My serviceRecord class has accesory list inside backend.

Comment: each time someone use formControlName and ngModel in the same input a little cat die.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `formArray` in a wrong way. You should use `formArrayName` and `index` in the template and also need to add `formControl` when you get the list from the backend.

So the code should be like in TS

```
const accesoryListControl = this.form.get('accesoryList') as FormArray;
this.accesoryList.forEach((accesory) => {
  accesoryListControl.push(new FormControl(accesory.checked));
});
```

and in HTML

```
<div formArrayName="accesoryList">
  <div *ngFor="let accesory of accesoryList; index as index">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="index" /> {{ accesory.name }}
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I created an example at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2sixzt?file=src%2Fmain.ts how to use it.

Comment: Thanks. That worked for me with a small configuration over object.